# Expecting 'Two of Hearts'. Instead getting a different output every single time

Tags: python, class

I am here getting a different result every time upon running and I have no idea what's wrong. Can somebody please help me out ? Thank You.

```
suits = {'Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs'}
ranks = {'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'}
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':11, 'Queen':12, 'King':13, 'Ace':14}
#card class 
class Card():
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank
        self.value=values[rank]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit
#deck class 
class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.all_cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
new_deck=Deck()
print(new_deck.all_cards[0])
```

I expected that the deck class would make a deck of 52 cards and by that logic the card at the 0th index should be two of hearts since hearts is the first suit in the 'suits' set at the top and two is the first rank in the 'ranks' set at the top. But I don't why I am getting a different card name printed in the terminal every time i run this code and not two of hearts.

Comment: Sets are not ordered. Use lists instead of sets if you want consistent results.

Comment: If you can't figure this out on your own then you need to learn how to use a debugger. That should be something any developer uses from day 1, otherwise you're going to train yourself to rely on others to help you debug trivial issues. You should know from the beginning how to step through your code line by line.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

You are defining sets by using {} which means they lose their ordering and you lose any duplicate values. You want to use list, which are defined by using []. To make your code work as expected you can redefine the variables suits and ranks as lists. For example

```
suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs']
ranks = ['Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
```